# Why isn’t the complexity of selection sort n factorial?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, big-o, selection-sort

If selection sort iterates over the array n times with n being the length of the array, with each iteration having 1 less comparison to make than the last (first iteration has n comparisons), how comes the complexity of selection sort is n^2 instead of n!(n factorial)?

Comment: The first time we iterate through the array, it takes n-1 comparisons. The second time, n-2 comparisons. The third time, n-3 comparisons. Etc. Finally the total number of comparisons is n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = n * (n - 1) / 2 < n². This is a much much smaller number than n! = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 3 * 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, multiplication of runtimes arises when you perform some operation some number of times. So, for example, if I do 10 operations 5 times, then I'd do 50 total operations.

On the other hand, addition of runtimes arises when you do one thing, then do the next, etc. So, for example, if I do 10 units of work, then 5 units of work, I'd do a total of 15 units of work.

You're correct that selection sort first looks at n items, then n-1 items, then n-2 items, then n-3 items, etc. The question is how we then go from that to a total runtime. You're proposing multiplying them together:

> n · (n-1) · (n-2) · ... · 2 · 1

However, this would mean "I do n things n-1 times, then do that n-2 times, then do that n-3 times, etc."

That's why instead we add them together:

> n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 = n(n+1)/2 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).